# Use Python to create chart with single shape/image per data point

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, waffle-chart

I want to create a chart that illustrates the count of a given binary variable using a single shape for each data point, and uses color to indicate if the value is 0 or 1.

The chart below shows an example similar to what I'm looking for. The only difference would be if any datapoints' "Success" value == 0, that point would be red, instead of green.

How might I most easily go about achieving this with Python? Is there a library with a turn-key solution for something like this? If not, how might I easily do this using Matplotlib?

[image]

Edit:
I've found another example used in a more "scientific" context. It appears to be called a "Waffle Chart". It appears this might then be a duplicate question, as there's an answer here: [How to do waffle charts in python? (square piechart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400136/how-to-do-waffle-charts-in-python-square-piechart)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that Matplotlib can do something like this. What you're looking for seems to be a UI feature rather than some kind of scientific plot.

Comment: Nice find in the edit!

Comment: If I vote to close this as a duplicate I think you are able to accept that automatically. That's if you want this closed as a dupe, which you seem to be suggesting in the edit. It's up to you since I don't know whether that question actually does what you want specifically.

Comment: I think the intention in the edit is clearly to mark this as duplicate. I just did so. In case there is some need for further clarification you may of course ask to reopen it.