# How to create a waffle chart with a dictionary?

Tags: python, waffle-chart

I'm learning Python via Jupyter lab and I'm facing a problem with Waffle chart.

I have the following dictionary, which I want to display as a Waffle chart:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pywaffle import Waffle

dic = {'Xemay':150,'Xedap':20,'Oto':180,'Maybay':80,'Tauthuy':135,'Xelua':5}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic, orient='index')

plt.figure(FigureClass=Waffle,rows=5,values=dic,legend={'loc': 'upper left', 'bbox_to_anchor': (1, 1)})
plt.title('Số lượng xe bán được của một công ty')
plt.show()
```

The result, however, is unexpected:

[image: Screenshot1]

Instead, the chart should look like this instead. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: To be clear are you using `PyWaffle` to create the chart? Would help people answer if you included your import explicitly

Comment: Yes I did import: import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pywaffle import Waffle
import collections
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
from PIL import Image
import folium
import geopandas as gpd
import math
import re
from folium import plugins

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do waffle charts in python? (square piechart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400136/how-to-do-waffle-charts-in-python-square-piechart)

Comment: Also see the nice introduction at the [project's page](https://github.com/gyli/PyWaffle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your code is correct and Waffle properly shows your data (zoom inside your plot to see the squares...)

However, to achieve the desired output, you have to play with the parameters "rows" and "columns", which specify the dimensions of your waffle chart.

```
nRows=5
countsPerBlock=10  # 1 block = 10 counts
plt.figure(FigureClass=Waffle,
           rows=nRows,
           columns=int(np.ceil(sum(dic.values())/nRows/countsPerBlock)),
           values=dic,
           legend={'loc': 'upper left', 'bbox_to_anchor': (1, 1.1)})
plt.show()
```

[image: Screenshot solution 2]

Note that waffle internally applies some rounding (see parameter [`rounding_rule`](https://pywaffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/class.html)), which is why `countsPerBlock` is not exactly true unless you scale the data yourself. To exactly reproduce the desired output, use the following code:

```
nRows = 5
countsPerBlock = 10
keys = ['Xemay', 'Xedap', 'Oto', 'Maybay', 'Tauthuy', 'Xelua']
vals = np.array([150, 20, 180, 80, 135, 5])
vals = np.ceil(vals/countsPerBlock)
data = dict(zip(keys, vals))

plt.figure(FigureClass=Waffle,
           rows=5,
           values=data,
           legend={'loc': 'upper left', 'bbox_to_anchor': (1, 1)})
plt.show()
```

[image: Screenshot solution final]

Alternatively, you could normalize your data such that the sum of values is 100. In a 5x20 square, one square will represent 1% of your data.

```
# Create a dict of normalized data. There are plenty of 
# ways to do this. Here is one approach:
keys = ['Xemay', 'Xedap', 'Oto', 'Maybay', 'Tauthuy', 'Xelua']
vals = np.array([150, 20, 180, 80, 135, 5])
vals = vals/vals.sum()*100
data = dict(zip(keys, vals))
nRows = 5
# ...
```

[image: Screenshot solution final]

Comment: Can we do it as normal value, not by percentage?

Comment: See the second part of my answer if you want that 1 count is represented by 1 block.

Comment: Also check the [docs](https://pywaffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) for more examples.

Comment: @TuyenDuong Your welcome :) Just added another update to my answer to exactly reproduce your output. I noticed that `Waffle` does some internal rounding.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 code options can solve my problem:

**1. Contribution from Mr.Normanius:**

```
nRows = 5
countsPerBlock = 10
keys = ['Xemay', 'Xedap', 'Oto', 'Maybay', 'Tauthuy', 'Xelua']
vals = np.array([150, 20, 180, 80, 135, 5])
vals = np.ceil(vals/countsPerBlock)
data = dict(zip(keys, vals))

plt.figure(FigureClass=Waffle,
           rows=5,
           values=data,
           legend={'loc': 'upper left', 'bbox_to_anchor': (1, 1)})
plt.show()
```

**2. From what I've learned:**

```
fig = plt.figure(
    FigureClass=Waffle, 
    rows=5, 
    values=df[0]/10, 
    title={'label': 'So luong xe duoc ban cua mot cong ty', 'loc': 'left'},
    labels=df.index.tolist(),
    legend={'loc': 'lower right', 'bbox_to_anchor': (1, 0.5)}
)
plt.show()
```

The result as below:
[image]