# How to create waffle chart?

Tags: jasper-reports, waffle-chart

I need to create a waffle chart that should show the percentage coverage of my project's data. We are using JasperReports, but unfortunately I couldn't find how to implement the report's design like this:

[image: Waffle chart example]

Maybe someone faced something similar?

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to Python, [PyWaffle](https://github.com/gyli/PyWaffle) could be the one you are looking for. It is a Python package based on [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).

Here is a similar question and more detailed introduction of the package:
[How to do waffle charts in python? (square piechart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400136/how-to-do-waffle-charts-in-python-square-piechart/47445913#47445913)